# What does "ADM" stand for on an article submission information page?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

On the information page of my article submission, there's a column titled "ADM", listing the name of two persons that I can email.

What does this stand for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this context, ADM probably means "administrator."  In other words, those are likely the people you are expected to contact in case of questions and problems with the submission site.

Answer (score 11):

There are two thing in Manuscript Information 
1.Editor-In-Chief called EIC or the 
2. Administrator Called ADM about a particular manuscript

Comment: Are EIC and ADM synonyms or they have different tasks? In my case there is no information about EIC but only ADM and the paper is "under review".

Answer (score 4):

You don't indicate which submission system you are speaking of, but the ScholarOne Manuscripts system, there are generally 3 levels of roles that deal with a submission. There is the administrator, who would preform some of the more routine tasks (checklists, adding notes, etc), this is commonly abbreviated as "admin" or "adm". The next level is an Editor. They can perform any number of tasks depending on the journals specific workflow, including finding and managing the review process, making recommendations and/or decisions. Journals refer to this role as many things depending on their business model. Editors (Ed.), Assistant Editor (AE), Section Editors (SE) are a few of the more common ones. Then there is an Editor In Chief role (EIC). They typically do the final decision, however, different journals will have various and widely differing workflows. Some journals have an EIC assign an Editor, who then manages the process from that point forward, with the EIC only approving the final outcome.
 Some journals don't have editors, only EIC's, some have no EIC's and only Editors. Some have 2 or 3 different flavors of Editors. Some smaller journals only have a very small staff, and they perform "all of the above".

Disclaimer: I am an employee at ScholarOne, but the opinions and posts here are my own.

Answer (score 0):

ADM, most probably stands for Article Dedicated Manager, not sure though.

ADM is a person in-charge of handling any communication about a specific article. His role is to answer general questions and to give advice to authors. In some cases to communicate with editors if questions require that. However, decisions of accepting or rejecting articles are usually made by EIC or other Editors in the editor board.