# A paper with two ADMs

Tags: peer-review, journals, acm

Is it normal for ACM journals to assign two ADMs? What does it mean? In what situation this can happen?

Does it mean that the journal accepted to review the paper? Does it means that the journal is in trouble finding the reviewer? Or even can its meaning be that the first ADM didn't accept to handle the paper?
(The paper has a multidisciplinary subject in computer science)

---

Edit: The abbreviation I used for ADM is exactly the label that ScholarOne website uses. It stands for Administrator.

I am not worried about the paper and I am not stressful for it. I just use every situation to learn and get more familiar with the situation. Maybe in the future someone asks me about it because of my experience. Something like what I have done now and asked the people with the same experience.

I actually believe that when the journal shows this information, so it is for us and that's not inherently wrong to try to understand its meaning.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Just sit back, relax, and wait for the reviews to come in due course.

Comment: What is ACM and ADM?

Comment: Possible related: [What does "ADM" stand for on an article submission information page?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56027/17254)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that "ADM" is the administrator role. It would simply mean that there may be two people who can do the administrator checklist. One of them will take care of your paper.

In general: You worry far too much. You submitted the paper, now let it go through the motions that papers have to go through, and eventually an email will be in your inbox that describes what people have decided. There is no point in checking frequently what the system may be telling you because there is *absolutely nothing you can infer* from what the system is saying until you get that email.

Rather, spend the time productively working on your next publication.

Comment: Do you mean that those two names written for ADM are options before their agreement? And one of them can accept to handle the paper process? Did I understand you correctly? Is it common in ACM journals? I know that this is not a common general rule for ScholarOne wesite to show the name of all possible options, since IEEE also uses ScholarOne and only show the name of assigned and agreed ADM. So, this must be journal specific, not website specific.

Comment: You're trying to read tea leaves. For many publishers, multiple admins are responsible for multiple journals. Someone will handle the paper administratively, and it could be any of the ones listed. It has nothing to do with who the publisher (ACM) is, or what online system (ScholarOne) they use. I really do think that you're spending far too much energy on this question, in particular because even if you knew the answer, there is absolutely nothing actionable for you. It's just a waste of your energy.